# When do you have to do the hotel assassination mission? GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When are you required to do the hotel assassination? I can't seem to find any information on it.
What is the last mission I can do before I am required to do the assassination mission to move on with the story?

Comment: Can't find accurate info on missions, but you may have been hit by an update which corrupted your save. [Official support page](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/200506327/What-to-do-if-no-further-missions-are-showing-up-in-GTAV-Story-Mode) says nothing can be done to fix a corrupted save, and has some suggestions on how to trigger unlocking a mission as they're not automatic as in most games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per gamefaq forum

You can't finish Blitz Play until you do the Hotel Assassination

You will get a text from Lester saying he needs Franklin's help ASAP and to go to him before doing that other job.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If you quote an external source it's better to link that, too.